# dispatch_group_wait not waiting

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, fbsdk

I'm having trouble waiting `**synchronously**` for an `async` call to the `Facebook Graph API`.

```
var message: String? = ""
var error: ErrorType?

let dispatchGroup = dispatch_group_create()
dispatch_group_enter(dispatchGroup)

FacebookGraphAPI.getPostsWithCompletionHandler("[pageID]", parameters: ["limit": 1]) {
    (posts, error) in

    if error != nil {
        error = ErrorType.Some
    }

    if posts == nil || posts!.count == 0 || !posts![0].createdTime.isToday {
        error = ErrorType.Some
    }

    if error == nil {
        message = posts![0].message
    }

    dispatch_group_leave(dispatchGroup)
}

dispatch_group_wait(dispatchGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)

if error != nil {
    throw error!
}

return message
```

getPostsWithCompletionHandler is my own function which I know always calls the specified handler.

Please help!

Comment: *Tell, don't ask*. Perform the task which proceeds the returned message in the completion handler.

Comment: Don't defeat the asynchronous pattern by waiting for completion. Proceed the returned result  in the completion handler.

Comment: Well that wont work with the rest of the code.

Comment: Show the code that interferes with asynchronous execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I solved by ditching the Facebook SDK and using contentsOfURL function instead because it's synchronous.